# How do I use multiple AMD graphic cards?

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics

I have 4 5830's in a intel 64bit powered machine.

I was having troubles with windows last night so I decided to try Ubuntu. I got all the to downloading and installed AMD's catalyst control center 13.1 for ubuntu.

My problem is:

I can run

```
$ sudo aticonfig --lsa
[sudo] password for user: 
 * 0. 01:00.0 ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series

 * - Default adapter
```

and find the first card in the first PCI lane. But none of the rest seem to show up even when I did

```
$ sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --initial
$ sudo rebot
$ sudo aticonfig --adapter=all --odgt

 Adapter 0 - ATI Radeon HD 5800 Series
        Sensor 0: Temperature - 67.00 C
```

I think the main problem is updating the MOBO BIOS which I am still trying to accomplish, does anyone know any solution to the issue I face above though?

I am trying to overall accomplish this http://www.distrogeeks.com/install-cgminer-2-10-4-ubuntu/

To install CGMiner on Ubuntu and get back to my mining!

EDIT:
I had posted a response on here from another account but I think this "Bruno" guy deleted it, as it was not from this account.

I ended up removing linux (it crashed, couldn't display anything??) and installed windows. Turned windows on, installed mobo drivers, worked perfectly? Detected all cards first try.......

That only thing I think fixed my problem was just moving the cards, and turn the computer on and off until it recognized them all. Other than that, that is the only fix.

Comment: This issue has been solved. Not sure of the fix. I literally kept switch around cards until it recognized all of them...

Answer (score 1):

Try to install additional driver from `system settings>aditional drivers`.

Comment: What will this do? What is in the "additional drivers"?

Comment: This is a tool to install open source drivers for ubuntu

Comment: @user1596244, It will detect if there are additional drivers available for your computer and give you the option to install them.

Comment: @Qeoqle OP already has drivers up and running, this answer is useless to the point where there are already drivers installed and running on the system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the bus id of each card with `lspci | grep VGA` and add each card to your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file as such

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Card1"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:1:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "Card2"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        BusID       "PCI:1:2:0"
EndSection
```

You can edit your xorg.conf file with any text editor, but you will need `sudo` rights for that.

Comment: This makes sense, I will see if I can do this when I get home. So lspci will list all hardware on the pci buses?

Comment: Yes, and `grep VGA` will show you only the graphics card information.